# Facebook graph api - /me/music returns empty array

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

i am using the right permission `user_actions.music`
i first authenticate the user with the scope above and then request /me/music, but it returns me an empty array.
using graph api v2.8

Comment: _“i am using the right permission”_ – not according to the documentation for /user/music.

Comment: thanks for pointing it out. indeed, i had another look at [/user/music/](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/music/). 
do i need all three if i just want to list the user's music pages?

Comment: No, you just need `user_likes`.